# Blackfire not working on Windows / WAMP

Tags: wamp, blackfire

Blackfire gives me "Are you authorized to profile this page? Probe not found or invalid signature." on my WAMP install!

I followed all the steps correctly and installed everything in the right places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Things to keep in mind while setting up Blackfire on WAMP:

- Make sure Xdebug and other debugging extensions are disabled in the php.ini file.
- *Client ID* and *Client Key* are different from *Server ID* and *Server Key* - see that you are not pasting them in the wrong places.
- Set up a log directory to make sure you get to know about errors. Example: `blackfire.log_file = /path/to/logs/blackfire.log`
- Make sure the *blackfire-agent.exe* is running while you try to profile the site running on your localhost - this is what I was missing. You can run it with the command `blackfire-agent` in the command prompt.

Hope it helps! Happy coding!

Comment: +2! Thanks for the point 4! After several tries and abandoning the blackfire, I feel so non-clever right now. :)